# Fixed height/width of bars in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I'm new with highcharts and what I'm trying to achieve is to have fixed bar height/width and fixed spacing between bars in highcharts. Either there are 20 bars or only 3 of them, the bar height/width and space between bars should remain the same. And the highchart itself should be with fixed height, f.e. 300px. I'm not sure this is doable, but here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/01maJ.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjOuy.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to only set fixed axis extremes:

```
    xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 4
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/5011/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.min

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a better solution, but this is one solution:

```
xAxis: {
  categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', '', '', '']
},
series: [
  {
    data: [5, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0]
  }
],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aabramya/jfdv3z65/7/